# Show toast while database is being copying

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlite

In the first run of my app, i have to copy database file to data folder. it takes about 10 sec and in this period of time user sees a black screen. I want to use AsynTask technique to show a Toast to user.

with this code i call copy database class and also i call AsynTsk process...

```
new asyn().execute();
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        // throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
```

and this is my AsynTask code:

```
    public class asyn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

     protected void onPreExecute(Void parmas2) {
         Context cntx = getApplicationContext();
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(cntx, "aaaaaaaaaaa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void parmas3) {

     }

 }
```

where is my fault? how i can fix that? i want show a toast in the middle of database copying.

Comment: What error do you see? what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand that `createDataBase` is the part that takes 10 seconds then,

You should move

```
try {
    myDbHelper.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // throw new Error("Unable to create database");
}
```

into the `doInBackground` method of the AsyncTask.

The AsyncTask works by calling `doInBackground` in a seperate thread, but the other methods (`onPreExecute`, etc) on the Ui Thread. If you want a toast to be displayed and not block the Ui thread with your database creation, you need to put the heavy work into `doInBackground`.